# Component not passing props to other component in same file when calling as const

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass props from one component to another. The `index` property in `SortableSectionList` does not seemed to be passed to `SortableSection` though. See console output below.

```
Index in SortableSectionList: 0
Index in SortableSectionList: 1
(2) Index in SortableSection: undefined
```

Other properties like `menuSection` get passed just fine though. See the full code below. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
import React from 'react'
import MenuSection from './MenuSection'
import { SortableContainer, SortableElement } from 'react-sortable-hoc'

class MenuSections extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const menuSections = this.props.menuSections

    const SortableSectionList = SortableContainer(({ menuSections, onSectionSortEnd }) => (
      <div>
        {menuSections.map(function(menuSection, index) {
          console.log('Index in SortableSectionList: ' + index)
          return (
            <SortableSection
              collection="section"
              key={`item-${menuSection.id}`}
              menuSection={menuSection}
              index={index}
              menuItems={menuSection.menuItems}
              onSortEnd={onSectionSortEnd}
            />
          )
        })}
      </div>
    ))

    const SortableSection = SortableElement(({ menuSection, index, menuItems, onSortEnd }) => {
      console.log('Index in SortableSection: '+index)

      return (
        <MenuSection
          key={menuSection.id}
          menuSection={menuSection}
          index={index}
          menuItems={menuItems}
          onSortEnd={onSortEnd}
        />
      )
    })

    return (
      <div>
        <SortableSectionList
          menuSections={this.props.menuSections}
          lockAxis="y"
          lockToContainerEdges
          onSortEnd={this.props.onSortEnd}
          onSectionSortEnd={this.props.onSectionSortEnd}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default MenuSections
```

Comment: Hey, there seems to be too many things inside the render() method. I would suggest you separate them into component methods or even new separate components.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that, see how it goes and update the question accordingly.

Comment: Nothing is jumping out as wrong in the code snippet. Are you still facing this issue?

Comment: Why are you defining `SortableSectionList` and `SortableSection` inside of `MenuSections` render method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `react-sortable-hoc` uses [`index` property](https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc#sortableelement-hoc) by itself. So if you want to use it also you better add another property like `sortIndex` or similar and pass it.

```
return (
  <SortableSection
    index={index}
    sortIndex={index}
    ...
```

They also have an [explanation and example](https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc#wrapper-props-not-passed-down-to-wrapped-component) in their docs.

Comment: Yep that was it, thanks! Appreciate the example link as well.